# Button Input Types, can I use Font Awesome Icons as a part of the value (Button Text)

Tags: jquery, font-awesome

I have a multi-page form that is button driven and I would like to know if it is possible to use jQuery to add awesome icons in the rendered button:

```
<input type="button" value="Contact Us" />
```

I would like to use http://fontawesome.io/icon/phone-square/ 
 (Unicode f098)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
<button type="button"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"> Contact Us</i></button>
```

if you have to use the  then try this (no need for js ...):

```
<input type="button" class="fa" value="&#xf098; Contact Us" />
```

this is the unicode value of fa-phone-square

```
&#xf098;
```

and tiny fiddle :) https://jsfiddle.net/cq27e802/

Comment: Thank you vidriduch.  I am using a Wordpress form plugin that renders the buttons automatically so I can't change the form elements.  I would have to manipulate them.  And they are output as input[type="button"] and not as button so I have to contend with the element value rather than the html

Answer (score 1):

> Thank you vidriduch. I am using a Wordpress form plugin that renders
>   the buttons automatically so I can't change the form elements. I would
>   have to manipulate them. And they are output as input[type="button"]
>   and not as button so I have to contend with the element value rather
>   than the html –  Requin Creative 11

```
$('input[type=button][value="Contact Us"]').replaceWith('<button type="button"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"> Contact Us</i></button>');
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/LcL55bgs/